# Dynamically select Area in ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a situation where I need to dynamically select the area based on some external criteria (in this case a read from my database).

I have the following standard structure in my MVC project:

- Areas

  - Area1
  - Area2
- Controllers
- Views

Now I want that when my users visit `http://mysite.com/private` they are will either be served with `Area1` or `Area2`, and I want to make that decision at runtime.

I guess I will have to inherit from `Route` or `RouteBase` and do my magic there, but I'm failing to understand how to do it.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: the routes will exist statically and you can just redirect users at runtime based on any decision in the `private` controller? No? An Area is just a bunch of pages under a namespace and url

Comment: That was not what I had in mind. Note that I don't have a `private` controller. the idea was to route requests to `/private/{controller}/{action}` to either `/Area1/{controller}/{action}` or `/Area2/{controller}/{action}`